# Combine database record into 1 record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to combine these 2 rows into 1 row leaving no empty fields.

I am using MS SQL Server 2016 :

[image]

Comment: For viewing purposes, or by physically merging the 2 rows in the table into 1?

Comment: for viewing purpose

Comment: So... group by and use max...

Comment: how can you max description?

Comment: Like you would anything else... `MAX(Description)` ... so if one record is empty/null, the other value will then be the max, and will be selected. If the data really as described, that should work. But if Description or caseId are filled in on the alternate rows...  well then.. it takes a bit more finesse...

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e4a6e/3)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
     ActivityId int,
     CaseId int, 
     Description varchar(255),
     Actions varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO MyTable (ActivityId,CaseId,Description,Actions) VALUES 
(229189,35057152,NULL,'DELETED'),
(229189,NULL,'DO','DELETED');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
     Max(ActivityId) AS ActivityId,
     Max(CaseId) AS CaseId,
     Max(Description) AS Description,
     Max(Actions) AS Actions 
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ActivityId;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e4a6e/3/0)**:

```
| ActivityId |   CaseId | Description | Actions |
|------------|----------|-------------|---------|
|     229189 | 35057152 |          DO | DELETED |
```

Comment: I would have left ActivityId, and Actions out of the MAX, but used them for the group by. What wasn't clear from the OP was if Actions could or would be different, and/or what to do in those cases. Unfortunately th sample data given was too narrow.